# Dropbox sync alike app, that use own web server

Tags: macos, sync, dropbox

Is there any Dropbox sync alike app , that can

-use own ftp server

-sync like Dropbox(if there is a change is local drive then auto upload to the ftp server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question has been asked on Askubuntu and there are a few option listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3678/make-my-own-dropbox-ubuntu-one-server-at-home/50396#50396)

Answer (score 0):

What are you goals for not using Dropbox? Are you trying to avoid storing your data with a third party? Or is it that you don't want to be restricted by the Dropbox storage limits?

If you wanted to just perform 1 way sync from your local drive to your ftp server you could write a script using `inotify` and `rsync`.

Answer (score 0):

A quick Google shows a lot of options; did you try that?

One reasonable option is [FTPbox](http://ftpbox.org/) - free, open source, and appears to monitor your files as you edit (similar to Dropbox).

EDIT:

For OSX, you might want to take a look at [Cyberduck](http://cyberduck.ch/).
If you're more technically-minded, take a look at [rsync](http://www.xelon.it/articles/rsync-mac-linux-windows/) - it may allow you more control.

Comment: oh sorry , i forgot to mention i am using macintosh

Comment: Ok - added tag to your question.